# Targeting specific "nth" HTML tags with PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, dom, html-parsing, web-scraping

I am using the PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser (http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to read through a website and output particular information.

I'm trying to output the contents of specific ,tr, tags in every table, and the contents of specific ,p, tags, rather than all tables and all paragraphs.

Therefore, Ideally I would like to set up some PHP code that involves numeric parameters which refer target specific "nth" ,td, or ,p, tags.

---

As a PHP novice, I greatly appreciate the expertise that is found on StackOverflow.
Thank you for your time and assistance in figuring out my questions.

The first question set is here, above the code.  The second question set can be found at the bottom of this post, with the PHP code.

---

1st question set:

A. How does one output the 2nd and 3rd  of every table?

AND

B. How does one output the 4th paragraph after every table and exclude the ,a, tag it contains?

IN

The following HTML code

USING

The PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser as shown in the following PHP code

UNLESS

You have a different suggestion that you believe is better

---

Below is sample HTML code followed by PHP code and another relevant question set.

This is the main HTML I am interested in.

```
<a name=“arbitrary_a_tag_Begin_Item_01”></a>
<h2>Item No. 1 </h2>

<table>

<tbody>

<tr>
<td>Item Description:</td>
<td>Big blue ball</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Property Location:</td>
<td>Storage Closet</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Owner:</td>
<td>Gym</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Cost</td>
<td>20.00</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Vendor:</td>
<td>Jim’s Gym Toys</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>

<p>
Approximate minimum acceptable grage sale price: $10
<br>
6 month redemption period
</p>

<p>
<img src="../dec/Item01.jpg">
</p>

<p>
<a target="new" href="http://pictures/Item01.jpg”>Picture of Item 01</a>
</p>

<p>
Current status: In Stock
<a name=“arbitrary_a_tag_Begin_Item_02></a>
</p>


<h2>Item No. 2 </h2>

<table>

<tbody>

<tr>
<td>Item Description:</td>
<td>Green tennis racket</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Property Location:</td>
<td>Gear Lockers</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Owner:</td>
<td>Tennis Team</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Cost</td>
<td>50.00</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Vendor:</td>
<td>Jim’s Gym Toys</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>

<p>
Approximate minimum acceptable grage sale price: $25
<br>
6 month redemption period
</p>

<p>
<img src="../dec/Item02.jpg">
</p>

<p>
<a target="new" href="http://pictures/Item02.jpg”>Picture of Item 02</a>
</p>

<p>
Current status: In Stock
<a name=“arbitrary_a_tag_Begin_Item_03></a>
</p>


<h2>Item No. 3 </h2>

<table>

<tbody>

<tr>
<td>Item Description:</td>
<td>Red Soccer Ball</td>
</tr>
```

Etc. etc. etc.

The PHP code USING "PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser":

```
<?php
// Include the library
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$url = 'http://www.URL.com';

// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html($url);

foreach($html->find('table') as $table) 
{
echo '<table><tbody>';
foreach($table->find('tr') as $tr) 
{   
echo '<tr>';
foreach($tr->find('td') as $td)  
{   
echo '<td>';
echo $td->innertext;
echo '</td>';
}
echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</tbody></table><br />';
}
```

---

Some things I have come across and unsuccessfully attempted to implement to access specific tags:

---

The First Concept

```
$e = $html->find('table', 0)->find('tr', 1)->find('td');
foreach($e as $d){
echo $d;
}
```

Second concept:

```
$file = file_get_contents($url);
preg_match_all('#<p>([^<]*)</p>#Usi', $file, $matches);
foreach ($matches as $match)
{
echo $match;
}
```

---

Second Question Set:

Regarding this first concept above,
How do I set up a while loop to iterate through, lets say 12 tables?
For example, this: $e = $html->find('table', 0)
reads only the first table.
Yet, I am not sure how to replace the 0 with a variable, such as $i, which can be autoincremented.

```
$i = 1;
while($i<=12){
What goes here??
}
$i++
```

Regarding the second concept,
How can I use this (or the first concept) to:

1. Return an array of all p tags after each table
2. Read through the string contents (the "contents") within each p tag, and check it against string (the "key")
3. Only return the string "contents" when the key string is found within the contents
4. Before outputting the returned "contents" featuring the matched string, exclude/remove a 2nd matched string from the information to be output  (for example, in the 1st Question Set, I want to grab everything within a specific ,p, tag, but exclude everything within the ,a, tag).

---

Thanks very much for your time and assistance!

Comment: tl;dr XPath might be a better fit for the kinds of things you're doing. http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php

Comment: Thanks Barmar! XPath looks a bit complex to wrap my mind around, though I will give it a shot.  In what ways do you think it is more practical to use than PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser?  (Just curious, I am a bit of a simpleton when it comes to PHP, hence I am using the this basic easy to use webscraper).

Also, I am curious about answers to the specific questions listed in my post. The while loop one seems pretty simple (1st question of 2nd set), but I can't get it to work.